# Calculating $\lim_{x\to \infty} (x+1) \cos \left(2\cos ^{-1}(\frac{x}{x + 1}) (a - \frac{1}{2})\right) - x$ using cosine expansions

Tags: calculus, limits, taylor-expansion

Question is:

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} (x+1) \cos \left(2\cos ^{-1}(\frac{x}{x + 1}) (a - \frac{1}{2})\right) - x$$

The answer is $4x-4x^2$ but I'm not sure how to get there. I have to use expansions of the cosine function but I have tried the Taylor (and MacLaurin) series and they end up canceling out unless I've done something wrong.

Note: I've seen a similar question on here before but the answer to the question does not mention any expansions and this is the part I am having trouble with.

Comment: Please, include the theory you've covered because we can't read your mind. Thank you. Avoid no-clue questions-those aren't suitable for this site. Show some effort. As phrased now, your post is missing context and details. Btw, your note isn't helpful. Imagine other people reading your post.

Comment: See [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/721644). Furthermore, if you see a related question, make sure you add it into the body of your post.

Comment: **Hint**: $\cos(2\theta)=2\cos^2(\theta)-1$.

Comment: First of all, if you find an answer, you should link it. Second, no, you don't have any context. Based on what I read, I don't know if you are a super intelligent toddler in kindergarden or maybe a student. Third, you have to show your calculations. Nevertheless, you should include all the theorems you've learned. I' m not the one who voted to close your question, so, some other people share my oppinion and we agree there is, indeed, a lack of context.

Comment: @Kcurse Does my post answers your question?

Comment: @S.H.W how did you apply L’Hopitals rule? I believe it answers the question but it hasn’t used any cosine expansions so I’m not sure on the method.

Comment: @Kcurse L'Hôpital's rule is one way to do that. I've also provided a solution which relies only on the fact $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$. You can prove that using expansion.

Comment: @s.h.w just one more question how did you get alpha +/- 1 in the last few steps?

Comment: @Kcurse Could you be more specific, please?

Comment: @s.h.w in the last steps of the two limits you multiplied together in L, you had alpha + 1 and alpha -1. How did you get those two results from the last step in the working out. I understand your working out for both of those limits until the last steps where it equals alpha.

Comment: @Kcurse See the edit, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $t = \frac{x}{x+1}$

$$(x+1) \cos \left(2\cos ^{-1}(\frac{x}{x + 1}) (a - \frac{1}{2})\right) - x =  \frac{\cos \left(2\cos ^{-1}(t) (a - \frac{1}{2})\right)}{1-t} - \frac{t}{1-t} = \frac{\cos \left(2\cos ^{-1}(t) (a - \frac{1}{2})\right) -t}{1-t} $$
If $x\to \infty$ then $t \to 1^{-}$. So we have

$$L = \lim_{x \to \infty}(x+1) \cos \left(2\cos ^{-1}(\frac{x}{x + 1}) (a - \frac{1}{2})\right) - x =\lim_{t \to 1^{-}}\frac{\cos \left(2\cos ^{-1}(t) (a - \frac{1}{2})\right) -t}{1-t} $$
Also $$\lim_{t \to 1^{-}}{\cos \left(2\cos ^{-1}(t) (a - \frac{1}{2})\right) -t} = \lim_{t \to 1^{-}} 1 -t = 0$$ So we are allowed to use L'Hôpital's rule. Let $\alpha =2(a-\frac{1}{2})$
$$\lim_{t \to 1^{-}}\frac{\cos(\alpha\cos ^{-1}(t)) -t}{1-t} = \lim_{t \to 1^{-}} 1 -\frac{\alpha\sin(\alpha\cos ^{-1}(t))}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$$
Applying again L'Hôpital's rule
$$\lim_{t \to 1^{-}} \frac{\sin(\alpha\cos ^{-1}(t))}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} = \lim_{t \to 1^{-}}\frac{\cos(\alpha\cos ^{-1}(t))}{t(1-t^2)^\frac{-1}{2}}\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} = \alpha$$
So the answer is $$L = 1- \alpha^2 = 1 - 4(a-\frac{1}{2})^2 = -4a(a-1)$$
This is confirmed by [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20%28%28x%2B1%29*cos%282*arccos%28%28x%29%2F%28x%20%2B%201%29%29%20%28a%20-%201%2F2%29%29%20-%20x%29%20as%20x%20to%20infty).

It's also possible to compute the limit using only trigonometry. Let $y =\alpha\cos ^{-1}(t)$
$$\lim_{t \to 1^{-}}\frac{\cos(\alpha\cos ^{-1}(t)) -t}{1-t} = \lim_{y \to 0^{+}} \frac{\cos(y) - \cos(\frac{y}{\alpha})}{1 - \cos(\frac{y}{\alpha})} = \lim_{y \to 0^{+}}\frac{-2\sin(\frac{y}{2} + \frac{y}{2\alpha})\sin(\frac{y}{2} - \frac{y}{2\alpha})}{2\sin^2(\frac{y}{2\alpha})} = \ \ -\lim_{y \to 0^{+}}\frac{\sin(\frac{y}{2} + \frac{y}{2\alpha})}{\sin(\frac{y}{2\alpha})} \times \lim_{y \to 0^{+}}\frac{\sin(\frac{y}{2} - \frac{y}{2\alpha})}{\sin(\frac{y}{2\alpha})}$$

Let $z = \frac{y}{2\alpha}$, multiply and divide by $z$ then separate two limits

$$\lim_{y \to 0^{+}}\frac{\sin(\frac{y}{2} + \frac{y}{2\alpha})}{\sin(\frac{y}{2\alpha})} = \lim_{z \to 0^{+}} \frac{\sin(\alpha z  + z)}{\sin(z)} = \lim_{z \to 0^{+}}\frac{z}{\sin(z)} \times \lim_{z \to 0^{+}}\frac{\sin(\alpha z  + z)}{z} = \alpha + 1$$
The first limit is $1$ and for the second one let $p = \alpha z + z$
$$\lim_{z \to 0}\frac{\sin(\alpha z  + z)}{z} = \lim_{p \to 0} (1+\alpha)\frac{\sin(p)}{p} = \alpha+1$$
Similarly $$\lim_{y \to 0^{+}}\frac{\sin(\frac{y}{2} - \frac{y}{2\alpha})}{\sin(\frac{y}{2\alpha})} = \alpha - 1$$
And again $L = -(\alpha+1)(\alpha - 1) = 1 - \alpha^2$